# How can I delete a member function created in oracle

Tags: oracle, ordbms

How can I delete a member function created inside oracle type object without dropping the entire type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used it but according [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/alter_type.htm#GUID-A8B449E7-E3A8-48F4-A4C6-5BB87B1841CD__I2112555) you might be able to use

```
alter type {type_name} DROP MEMBER {function_spec} CASCADE;
```

Note, `{function_spec}` is the function name plus RETURN clause, e.g.

```
ALTER TYPE ttest DROP MEMBER FUNCTION f_name_2 RETURN VARCHAR2 CASCADE;
```

Afterwards you have to re-create the TYPE BODY without the dropped function, i.e. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY ...`

Comment: True, it works. Didn't know that, so - thank you, @Wernfried.

Comment: I am quite sure that this was not possible in earlier versions of Oracle. Perhaps it was added in 11. 2

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't (unless you call CREATE **OR REPLACE** to be *not dropping*).

P.S. What's even worse, if there are dependent types that use the type with a member function you'd want to drop, you'll need to *drop everything cascade*. Which means that - as a function doesn't have to eat or drink - leave it alone.

**[EDIT; after seeing Wernfried's answer]**

It seems that I was wrong. Apparently, it really works. Syntax is somewhat *strange* (it requires to specify the RETURN clause (?!?)), but hey - that's what Oracle says. So, today I learnt something new.

An example:

```
SQL> create or replace type ttest is object
  2    (some_name varchar2(20),
  3     member function f_name return varchar2
  4    );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type body ttest as
  2    member function f_name
  3      return varchar2
  4    is
  5    begin
  6      return self.some_name;
  7    end f_name;
  8  end;
  9  /

Type body created.

SQL> alter type ttest drop member function f_name return varchar2;

Type altered.

SQL> desc ttest
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SOME_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

Comment: can you please check "desc ttest " command and see whether the function has been removed from type.Because for me too it gave the output as type altered,yet the type have function

Comment: Sure; I did and updated my message by adding result of the DESC command. Database version is 11.2.0.4.0